# Kafka Stream program is reprocessing the already processed events

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I forwarded few events to Kafka and started my Kafka stream program. My program started processing the events and completed. After some time I stopped my Kafka stream application and  I started again. Observed that My Kafka stream program is processing the already processed previous events.

As per my understanding, Kafka stream internally maintains the offset for input topics itself per application id. But here reprocessing the already processed events.

How to verify up to which offset Kafka stream processing was done? How Kafka stream persisted these bookmarks? On what basis & from which Kafka offset, Kafka stream will start read the events from Kafka?

If Kafka steam throws exceptions then is it reprocessed already processed events?

Please clarify my doubts.

Please help me to under stand more.

Comment: The question provided very limited context and thus it hard to answer... Please provide more more context information.

Comment: Hi Matthias, I edited my question with few more doubts in elaborated way. Please clarify it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Streams internally uses a `KafkaConsumer` and all running instances form a consumer group using `application.id` as `group.id`. Offsets are committed to the Kafka cluster in regular intervals (configurable). Thus, on restart with the same `application.id` Kafka Streams should pick up the latest committed offset and continue processing from there.

You can check committed offset as for any other consumer group using `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh` tool.

Comment: Thanks Matthias your provided valuable information. One more doubt. How to change this committed offset to my required position to reprocess again. I read about zookeeper-shell.sh. But not working for me with this. Please provide the information.

Comment: In Kafka `1.0`, `bin/kafka-consumer-group.sh` allow to set custom offsets: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-122%3A+Add+Reset+Consumer+Group+Offsets+tooling Offsets are stored in ZK only in older Kafka versions -- since 0.9 offsets are stored in a topic in the Kafka Cluster itself: